# Connection between the two expressions of fisher information

Tags: mathematical-statistics, intuition, fisher-information, equivalence

I've seen two major expressions for the fisher information:

> $$I_{\mathbf{X}}(\theta) = \mathbb{V}ar(\ell'(\theta|\mathbf{X}))$$
>   where $\ell(\theta)$ is the log-likelihood function for $\mathbf{X}$,

and also, under regularity conditions

> $$I_{\mathbf{X}}(\theta) = -\mathbb{E}(\ell''(\theta|\mathbf{X}))$$
>   again where $\ell(\theta)$ is the log-likelihood function for $\mathbf{X}$.

I somewhat understand the intuition/idea behind them individually:

- In the variance definition, it is how much the gradient of the log-likelihood function varies from sample to sample. (However, I don't understand why high variance of this slope would mean $\mathbf{X}$ would carry a lot of information about $\theta$.)
- In the second expression, it is the average curvature for the likelihood function at a particular value of $\theta$. If there is very strong curvature, the value of the peak would be far more likelihood compared to its neighbourhood, so the $\mathbf{X}$ when observed would carry strong inference about the value of $\theta$, since the MLE will be very apparent.

(Please correct if there is anything inaccurate above)

I happen to think the second expression is far more intuitive compared to the first. I struggle to see what the variance of the slope would have to do with the information carried by $\mathbf{X}$. Also, I'm not quite sure what the condition would be between the two expression -> why would high expected curvature mean high variance or vice versa?